Advice on tooling for development environment
I am working with a set of microservices and a database that are currently being set up by developers on Mac, Linux, and Windows workstations each with their own idiosyncrasies. The production application is containerized using Docker and deployed on AWS ECS, but the local set up does not currently use containers.
What are my current tooling options to research with the goal of creating a more standardized development environment across operating systems and reduce the onboarding time for new developers? How might choices affect developer ease in things like logging, debugging, and hot reloading?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

To standardize your development environment across Mac, Linux, and Windows, consider using Docker for local development, mirroring your production setup. This ensures consistency across operating systems and simplifies onboarding. Docker Compose can manage multi-container setups, making it easier to handle microservices. For logging, debugging, and hot reloading, tools like docker logs, IDE integrations (e.g., Visual Studio Code with Docker extensions), and bind mounts for live code updates are effective.


Ensure everyone, regardless of OS, uses Bash and Linux-friendly file paths and naming conventions.
Windows users should install WSL
Ensure everyone knows how to work with docker and docker-compose at the command line.
local set up does not currently use containers --everyone should have a local set up that uses containers!
Create a private Docker registry to make it easier to share Docker images with your team.

